# Angular 2 (Typescript) Time Format

Tags: angular, datetime, typescript

I have this source of date :

TimeR ="2017-02-17 19:50:11 UTC";

In the Html file i used this code

```
<span class="text-lg">{{TimeR | date: 'hh:mm'}}</span>
```

It works good, but i just got the time without AM/PM, how can i fix it or how can get the date like this (for example 10:00 pm - 22:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with dates and times recently, and I would suggest you to look into [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/). You can easily create your own pipe with something as follows:

```
return moment("2017-02-17 19:50:11 UTC", "YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s z").format("H:m");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `mediumTime` to the pipe this should add the AM PM to your output. For future reference use [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)

```
{{ TimeR | date:'mediumTime' }}
```

Hope that helps